# Android and Blackberry project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry, share

I'm fairly new to android and have only really been using eclipse for some basic Blackberry work so I was curious if I could pick a few expert's minds for any suggestions/pointers on the workspace/project setup you use for dual platform support projects in eclipse?

I've found about 80% of my code is common between Blackberry and Android so it's this 20% I'm needing to address.

My current thinking is to have one workspace with shared source in multiple projects via setting them in the source tree options.

Where platform specific features are used I'll tag the source name as *Android_???* and *Blackberry_???* respectively and have a generic class that both projects point to.

I.e. effectively one workspace holds both Android and Blackberry setups and in the workspace have one project for Blackberry and one for Android but each project shares the same filesystem with the appropritate other platform's source files excluded from the build.

If only there was an easy way of doing the `#ifdef` equivalent in java this would simplify this port but I guess we have to do it without.(I heard about using a c preprocessor to do this but sounds messy so unless it's highly recommended I'd rather not adopt this)

I'd heard about creating a shared library but have a feeling these are not compatible between android and blackberry so any advice on this approach is also welcome.

Comment: why don't you create abstract classes, put your common code in those classes, create abstract methods for platform specific work. Then extend these classes in each of your project and implement the abstract methods accordingly

Comment: Seems a sensible approach but I'm curious about if it's recommended to share source directories and share workspaces for blackberry and android apps.

Comment: I would suggest keeping a common workspace and sharing source directories

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is really appreciated and what I've done now.  I've been making some headway with this but it's becoming an absolute nightmare as the Blackberry and Android plugins keep interfering with each other somehow and I now have a random build error in my unit tests.  I'm sure this is a newbie error I'm doing but can't find it for the life of me.  'Could not get project nature of the referred project ????'  I'll continue and will update this post if I get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably too late, but I'll still give you my thoughts on that.

I have a similar need. I have common code and Blackberry and Android specific parts. I have three separate Eclipse project for each part. The "specific" projects are the one actually run, and they both have a project dependancy (which I find cleaner than source inclusion) on the Common one.

Note that the Common project must be a Blackberry project (created using the plugin), since a Blackberry project cannot depend on a non-blackberry project.

It's working well for me!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else facing this issue I've found the solution that worked was by creating 3 directories on disk

Common
Blackberry
Android

The vast majority goes into Common however the classes that have platform specific calls go into the Blackberry/Android counterparts respectively and extend a common base class in the common directory.

E.g. a class called MyClass that needed platform specific versions would have a MyClassCommon in the common directory and in the Blackberry directory it has MyClass extends MyClassCommon definition and the same for Android.

In Eclipse the Common,Blackberry,Android src paths are individually added via a common variable (trunk) which is extened to the Common,Blackberry,Android paths for the 3 src root imports.

This seemed to be the only mechanism to ensure that the package name was consistent across platforms so not having a knock on effect that other dependent classes needed new package names.

I'm sure there is a more elegant/correct way of doing this but this appears to work well for now.