# Eclipse setup for Android and Blackberry

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry

Does anybody have a single Eclipse installation for both Blackberry and Android development?

I have the BB Plugin working fine.  I am wondering if I can just follow the Android installation steps without it affecting the BB setup.

I dont want to experiment, so I am asking.

I have seen this thread - [Android and Blackberry project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350623/android-and-blackberry-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: "I dont want to experiment, so I am asking"   Why don't you want to experiment?

Comment: @MichaelDonohue Man!, not everybody have a good internet connection/computer/time...i get some trouble to install eclipse, SDK, blablabla coz my internet speed is...horrible so i think he is right, for me, it's better to ask first @_@

Comment: "ask first" is a terrible policy when looking for volunteers to help you.  Try to help yourself first.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have a working Eclipse installation for both BlackBerry and Android development.

You must install the 'BlackBerry Plugin for Eclipse' from RIM first (which you've already done). Essentially it's the Eclipse IDE (currently Helios 3.6) with the BlackBerry plugin hardcoded into it.

Apart from the BlackBerry stuff, there are no other differences between the vanilla Helios 3.6 and the RIM 'BlackBerry Plugin for Eclipse', this means you can install the Android development tools into your IDE with no problems.

Works like a charm if you follow the guide here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Answer (score 1):

How to use single eclipse for Android and Blackberry ..?
Ans:
There was no any single setup available which work for both android and blackberry.
but in a simple thing the eclipse version 3.6 is work for blackberry plugin and as well as work with Android ADT-12 plugin so first of all you need to configure your blackberry and than you have to install any ADT plugins (i.e. the latest adt version is ADT-12) and than config the android sdk.
now your blackberry and android are working.
when you want to use blackberry than you open perspective option and select blackberry application development perspective.
and same when you want to use android than you may select java perspective...
try it..